# A word for someone plays on your insecurities?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Someone knows that you are insecure, and they say/do things knowing it will trouble your insecurities. They appear to enjoy the awkward reactions

Comment: Obligatory XKCD - https://xkcd.com/1027/

Comment: @marcellothearcane Brilliant. A Negger?

Comment: Yes, that probably works.  Watch out though, that comic was ill-received from pickup artist (negger) communities! http://tynan.com/xkcd, https://www.reddit.com/r/xkcd/comments/3oojgp/id_like_to_talk_a_bit_more_about_1027_pickup/, https://www.reddit.com/r/xkcd/comments/qohg8/pickup_artist/ to name a few...

Comment: A search for 'negger' reveals 'Schwarzenegger', which is confused with racism even though it actually means ['black ploughman'](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/etymology-of-the-name-schwarzenegger.2153532/) maybe 'so-and-so *negs*', 'I neg', 'he likes negging' etc

Comment: Manipulative works in a case like this. Bully, and Player, too.

Answer (score 1):

[**Predator**, according to OLD:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/predator)

> (disapproving) a person or an organization that uses weaker people for their own advantage